# EIRP conversion from given value at one polarization to both bolarization when antenna operate at both polarizations

Tags: digital-communications, power-spectral-density

For an antenna that operates in both polarizations, how do I convert its EIRP density, given in dBW/Hz assuming one polarization, to the dBW/Hz value for both polarizations?

For instance, if EIRP = -76.47 dBW/Hz/pol (this is the value assuming one polarizations), technical documents simply give -73.46 dBW/Hz due to both polarizations. I'm not sure how we are getting about 3.01 dB more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The extra 3.01 dB is simply $10\log_{10}2$, a factor of 2 accounting for equal power in each of the two polarizations.